# How to omit canceled events in Google Calendar:list method?

Tags: java, google-api, google-calendar-api

[Event:list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) method from `Google Calendar API v3` returns all events page by page. This method returns all events, even already canceled. How to omit canceled events in listing process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are they(deleted events) recurring events or single events. Be sure that they are not recurring events.

Comment: Actually, you are right. Now I understand a documentation. This method returns instances of deleted recurrent events. Thanks for pointing me on wright direction.

Answer (score 2):

The Event:list method only returns cancelled events if the showDeleted parameter is set to True. I just tried and confirmed this. [Documentation here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list#showDeleted)

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work for me. When I set this parameter to `false` this method retrieves all events but canceled events contain only basic data (id, kind, ...). When I set this parameter to `true` this method retrieves all events and canceled events contain all data.